# Why ethereum transaction fee has increased so high?

Tags: fees

I'm wondering what has caused this recent spike?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The increase has mostly been caused by the interest in DeFi (Decentralized Finance). Interest has soared so users are submitting more transactions to participate in DeFi.

Here you can see the increase in interest (the amount of assets locked up in DeFi): https://defipulse.com/ . You can see that in maybe just two months the amount has gone up from 1 billion to over 6 billion. And the amount keeps on rising, so maybe transaction fees will also keep rising - who knows.

Comment: ETH 2.0 will (hopefully) decrease the tx fees again

Comment: Oh yes, in the far far future :)

Comment: trades on decentralized exchanges are expensive